# Alternative to nested loops with fourth level depth in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis-3, select-by-attribute, for-loop

I am developing a processing plugin for QGIS 3.10. I want to avoid nested loops when filtering one layer based on another layer. How can I implement this?

I created some random layers/data for this questions we have the following layers:

- staff
- department
- company
- staff_assignment
- department_company

the following picture shows sample data from each table:

[image]

We start with a filter in the `'staff'` table (in the code I used `"gender"='male'`) then we move to `'staff_assignment'` and based on the staff `"ID"` we find `"department_id"` then we move to department-company  based on `"department_id"` to find the `"company_id"` at the end we go to company table and find the information we need.

Here is the code

```py
def initAlgorithm(self, config):

        parameter=QgsProcessingParameterMultipleLayers(
                'qgs_layers',
                self.tr('Input layers')
                )
        
        parameter.setMinimumNumberInputs(1)
        self.addParameter(parameter)

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):

        #Creating self layer to be used in program
        for layer in self.parameterAsLayerList(parameters, 'qgs_layers', context):
            layer_name=layer.name()
            try:
               exec('self.' + str(layer_name).replace(' ','_')+'_layer_obj=layer')
            except:
                pass
        
            
            
        filter=unicode(f'"gender" = \'Male\'')
        staff_features=self.staff_layer_obj.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression (filter))
        for sFeat in staff_features:
            staff_name=sFeat['first_name']+' '+ sFeat['last_name']
            staf_id=sFeat['id']
            filter_staff_assignment=unicode(f'"staff_id" = \'{staf_id}\'')
            staff_assignment_features=self.staff_assignment_layer_obj.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression (filter_staff_assignment))
            for saFeat in staff_assignment_features:
                department_id=saFeat['department_id']
                filter_department_company=unicode(f'"department_id" = \'{department_id}\'')
                department_company_features=self.department_company_layer_obj.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression (filter_department_company))
                for dcFeat in department_company_features:
                    company_id=dcFeat['company_id']
                    filter_company=unicode(f'"id" = \'{company_id}\'')
                    company_features=self.company_layer_obj.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression (filter_company))
                    for cFeat in company_features:
                        #do Something
                        company_name=cFeat['name']
                        feedback.pushInfo(f'{staff_name} works for {company_name} ')


        
        output={}
        return output
```

As you can see in the code it has a nested loop with 4 layers deep.
My program works fine with small data (1000 features in each layer) but when data set is big (about 10000 features in each layer) it takes forever to finish (about 27 hours).

How can I solve this issue (speed problem)?
The layers are in TAB or GeoJSON format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like the perfect use case for a relational database.

Your code is slow because it loops through the entire contents of three layers for each entry in the first one. And it does that exponentially. The first layer gets looped through one, the second one gets looped through for every feature in the first layer, then the third one is number of first layer features * number of second layer features * number of third layer features.

With a relational database it would use indexes to make those queries fast.

So the query would be:

```
select staff.staff_name, company.company_name
from staff
left join staff_assignment on staff.id = staff_assignment.staff_id
left join department_company on staff_assignment.department_id = department_company.company_id
left join company on department_company.company_id = company.id
where staff.gender = 'male'
```

Might need to adjust the joins, your table logic is a bit confusing. Do you really need to split it up so much? Also make sure there is an index on all of the columns used in the joins.

Comment: the data I provided in the question is randomly generated data. due to confidentiallity i cannot share the actual data. the data i use as an input is mapinfo(.TAB) and geojson.
Can you please expand your your answer on how i can use this query inside my python code.
Do i need to convert the input data to database format?

Comment: Yes you would put it into a database like PostgreSQL/PostGIS, and query using package like Psycopg2.